# Home page for 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

I'd like to make the area circled click able to a category page. Can't find in the code.

Answer (score 2):

I could just tell you the file but Magento has a featured called template hints that will enable you to figure this out for yourself.

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

- In your Magento admin go to System > Configuration,
- The select the Developer tab at the very bottom of the left sidebar
- Then select either the website or store view you'd like to debug from the top left Configuration Scope Switcher.[image]
- This will then add a new option to the debug section called "Template Path Hints"  [image]
- set that to yes and click save.

You will then be able to see the filename for the template that contains that text on the frontend.

[image]

Comment: Not it's not @fedmich, what are you referring to that is found in that file?